# Rails Checkboxes as array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, forms, checkbox

I'm trying to pass multiple checkboxes as array to a db table.
So i want to add multiple topics to a project.

```
= form_for @project, url: admin_projects_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |p|
  %p
    =p.label :name
    =p.text_field :name 
  %p
    = p.label :topic
  %p
    = p.label "Value1"
    = p.check_box(:topic, {:multiple => true}, "value1", nil)
    = p.label "Value2"
    = p.check_box(:topic, {:multiple => true}, "value2", nil)
    = p.label "Value3"
    = p.check_box(:topic, {:multiple => true}, "value3", nil)
  %p
    = p.submit
```

but here topic returns nil in the projects, even whenever i check multiple checkboxes
(i added to the whitelist params in the controller, so that cant be the cause)

What am i doing wrong here?

EDIT:

This is the code of the controller:

```
def new
  @project = Project.new
end

def create
  @project = Project.new(project_params)

  if @project.save
    redirect_to admin_projects_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end

private
# param white listing

def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description, :photo, :project_type, :highlight, :content, :topic, :category)
end
```

**Solution found:**

View was correctly.

```
 serialize :topic
```

needed be added to the project model

and the permit params should be edited so they only accept arrays on topic

```
private
# param white listing

def project_params
  params[:project][:topic] ||= []
  params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description, :content, topic: [])
end
```

Comment: Possibly unrelated but you don't need to make the form multipart unless you plan on having a file upload field in there.  I'd expect that to send through `params[:project][:topic] = ["value1", "value2", "value3"]`.  Can you please make an edit to your question and add what is actually coming through in  params when you check all the checkboxes and submit the form?  Also, add to your question the controller code which uses those params.  It's possible that your view code is not the problem.

Comment: I having a fileupload aswell in it. but removed that to keep it clean for stackoverflow. Even when i check all the checkboxes, it returns nil.

Comment: Add the params submitted by the form as well please.

Comment: ?? all the other params submit with no problem and correctly, only the checkboxes with array give nil back

Comment: Well, if you **ADD THE PARAMS TO YOUR QUESTION SO THAT WE CAN SEE THEM SOMEONE MIGHT BE ABLE TO DIAGNOSE THE ISSUE**.  Sorry for shouting but i've asked you twice now and you seem to not be comprehending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you save array in database add this to your model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :topic
end
```

**UPDATE**

And make your form as:

```
 %p
   = p.label "Value1"
   = p.check_box(:topic, {:multiple => true}, "value1", nil, name:"project[topic][]")
   = p.label "Value2"
   = p.check_box(:topic, {:multiple => true}, "value2", nil, name:"project[topic][]")
   = p.label "Value3"
   = p.check_box(:topic, {:multiple => true}, "value3", nil, name:"project[topic][]")
```

and if you get permitted  parameter issue add like:

```
params.permit! #only if you get issue of permitted parameter
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: sadly that did not fix it. "syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting =>" because of the " => []" inside the permit of the controller and :topic[] is giving an error in the view aswell

Comment: it works with permit! inside the controller ( name wasnt needed ), but i want to work with whitelisting of the permit, so i have to look into that how to do that with arrays